# Automate Facebook sign up process using selenium using java, but not able to select radio button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click on "Create an account" button on facebook login page. We cannot store the radio button into List as there is not separate web element as Gender.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)     {

        WebDriver fb = new FirefoxDriver();     

        fb.get("https://www.facebook.com/");   
        fb.findElement(By.xpath("id('u_0_1')")).sendKeys("Tomprakash");
        fb.findElement(By.xpath("id('u_0_3')")).sendKeys("Sahu");
        fb.findElement(By.xpath("id('u_0_6')")).sendKeys("7869084527");
        fb.findElement(By.xpath("id('u_0_9')")).sendKeys("7869084527");
        fb.findElement(By.xpath("id('u_0_b')")).sendKeys("cs083595");
        Select date = new Select(fb.findElement(By.xpath("id('day')")));
        date.selectByVisibleText("24");
        Select month = new Select(fb.findElement(By.xpath("id('month')")));
        month.selectByVisibleText("Dec");
        Select year = new Select(fb.findElement(By.xpath("id('year')")));
        year.selectByVisibleText("1989");
        fb.findElement(By.className("_58mt")).click(); //this code is working for female
        //fb.findElement(By.className("_5k")).click(); //this code is not working for male
        fb.findElement(By.name("Create an account")).submit();
    }

}
```

Comment: are you telling that you are not able to select male radio button?

Comment: I dont see a webelement with name "Create an account". you can use By.id("u_0_j") for sign up. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, it is working for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id=u_0_j]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id=u_0_n]")).click();
```

Comment: By.cssSelector is not a function, I'm using exactly the code you used. I'm using selenium webdriver for JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

we can select only one radio button

public class DropDownDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\sruthi-selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    //text fields
    driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_j")).sendKeys("sruthi");
    driver.findElement(By.name("lastname")).sendKeys("karpuram");
    driver.findElement(By.name("reg_email__")).sendKeys("84521636866");
    driver.findElement(By.name("reg_passwd__")).sendKeys("il9HNJ1234");

    //static drop down
    Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("day")));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    s.selectByVisibleText("12");

    Select s1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month")));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    s1.selectByValue("5");

    Select s2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year")));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    s2.selectByValue("1993");
    //radio button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='2']")).click();//for selecting male

    driver.findElement(By.name("websubmit")).click();

    driver.close();



}
```

}